# how do i enable a disabled button when the entire form is filled (C#)

Tags: c#

I want my `button` to be  enable once the entire form is filled. what code shoud I use
it is a windows form application

```
if (textBox1!= null && textBox2 != null && textBox3 != null && textBox4 != null && textBox5 != null && textBox6 != null && textBox7 != null && textBox8 != null && textBox9 != null && textBox10 != null)
{
    button2.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
    button2.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with what u have tried

Comment: why not use required field validator?

Comment: I don't know why people have attempted to answer this question without the answer to @SergeyBerezovskiy's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Use the text changed event of textboxes and call updateuserinterface method Like :

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    UpdateUserInterface();
}

private void UpdateUserInterface()
{
    if (textBox1!= null && textBox2 != null && textBox3 != null && textBox4 != null &&         textBox5 != null && textBox6 != null && textBox7 != null && textBox8 != null && textBox9 != null && textBox10 != null)
            {
                button2.Enabled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
}
```

Comment: @Brain Really? How did the `textBox1!= null` part and others "worked"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using WinForms and that you have only `TextBox` controls you can try this:

```
button2.Enabled = true;

foreach (var testBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        button2.Enabled = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

And even more concise version:

```
button2.Enabled = !this
    .Controls
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));
```

Comment: tried putting this code in the form_load function but it didnt work... where should i enter this code

Comment: @user3164631 I can't really guess what do you want to achieve. Just put it anywhere you want it to have the desired effect. For example, if you want to control the button in real-time, create a private function with this code, and call it from "TextChanged" event of each TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have numerous ways to do this, one simple way would be like this, note that your `TextBox` controls **shouldn't** be in a `Container` control like `GroupBox` or `Panel`:

```
button2.Enabled = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(c => c.Text.Length != 0);
```

**I assume that you are using WinForms**

Answer (score 0):

Use **RequiredFieldValidation** for all your text box

eg:

```
 <asp:TextBox id="Text1" 
      Text="Enter a value" 
      runat="server"/>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
      ControlToValidate="Text1"
      Text="Required Field!" 
      runat="server"/>
```

Set the Button `Enabled=false` property false. when all text boxes are filled out make it `enabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the text box content like below

```
if (textBox1.Text.Trim() != string.Empty && textBox2.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
```

**Update** : You can also use String.IsNullOrEmpty method as mentioned by Sergey Berezovskiy below

Comment: There is a method `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: @  Sergey Berezovskiy, Agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe the event named "Loaded" of you form in WPF application, or event named "Load" in windows form application.